# What is the quota cost for using the LiveChat in YouTube Data API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

We are currently using YouTube Data API for a live streaming app called CameraFi Live.
First of all, we want to know the quota cost for using the LiveChatMessages. It is not mentioned in the YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost).
For our app, LiveChatMessages takes up 80~90% of the total quota of the YouTube Data API and I think this percentage is unreasonably too much since it results in exceeding YouTube Data API quota. Is there any way to lower the amount (percentage) that is taken up by LiveChatMessages from the total quota of YouTube Data API? If there are any alternative ways to solve this problem, please tell us.

Answer (score 2):

It's not documented yet, but the quota cost is 20 to just retrieve the endpoint. When requesting `part` it's +0 for `id`, +1 for `snippet` and +1 for `authorDetails`, making it 22 total for everything you may want from that endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

[LiveChatMessages](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list) is part of the [YouTube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started) there for the [quota calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) for the YouTube Data API isn't going to help you.

If you check documentation for the live chat messages it doesn't say that it takes more then one.   So I would have to say the quota cost is one.

Remember this is two different APIs.  Live streaming API and data API are different.  There quota cost is also different.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing it appears the current (Feb 2019) cost of the LiveChatMessages endpoint is a base of 6 units, with +0 for id, +1 for snippet, and +1 for authorDetails.