# How many quotas does a LiveChatMessage insert request cost to the Youtube Live Streaming API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota

How many quotas does a LiveChatMessage insert request cost to the Youtube Live Streaming API ?

Comment: Related to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35401695).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LiveChatMessage insert request cost 20 quota

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).